# Is there a way to change Sms Limit from android studio?

Tags: android, sms

I am creating an app for a person I know for his company, he needs to send many SMS to his workers(shifts mostly). He asked me to create this app but now after I almost fished it I found out that there an SMS limit, is there a way to change it from the app with permissions or something and not make him dig through his root? Or at least make the annoying message pop up just once and not for every message that sends after the limit reached?

Comment: you cant do that directly from android app.you must need to use third party library and api for sending unlimited sms like twilio etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to change it from the app with permissions or something

No, sorry.

> Or at least make the annoying message pop up just once and not for every message that sends after the limit reached?

No, sorry.

If you wish to send bulk text messages, use a hosted SMS delivery service, such as Twilio.

Comment: Yeah that sucks, shame they didn't place it behind a dangerous permission and just placed it in root. Now I have to scrap all the automation message sending in the app.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use abd command to open that restrictions here is the link for tutorial
[change sms limit](https://www.xda-developers.com/change-sms-limit-android/)

1. Go to the android platform tool directory
   (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools)
2. open command shell by using Shift+mouserightclick
   and enter this command

   `adb shell`
   `settings put global sms_outgoing_check_max_count 5`

   `settings put global sms_outgoing_check_interval_ms 9000000`

I am actually reducing the number so Android warns me if I have sent more than 5 SMS messages within 30(9000000) minutes. Change “5” to whatever number you wan

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Comment: has this been tested? is it safe?

Comment: yes tested and safe